# JQuery and getting 1 one hidden value among many forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple forms like so:

```
<form method="post" action="change.php" id="form1">
   <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="abc" />
   <input name="button_name" id="submit1" type="submit" value="ADD" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="change.php" id="form2>
   <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="xyz" />
   <input name="button_name" id="submit2" type="submit" value="ADD" />
</form>
```

etc.

When I have one form I know how to get just one value, but how can I get the hidden value corresponding to the button click?
E.g.- so that clicking on form2's button I get "xyz"?

Or would it be better to have a big big form spanning my whole page and attach the hidden value's to the button itself? (I only have one value I need passing to change.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code attaches a handler to *all* forms, but gets the value of the hidden field in whichever form was the one associated with the current submit event:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   var $product_id = $(this).find('input[name="product_id"]');
   alert("Value within form " + this.id + ": " +$product_id.val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jB88N/

Obviously you'd do something more useful than just alerting the value, but the above shows how to get it. Within the handler, `this` is the form being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a single event handler for all your forms.

```
$('form[id^="form"]').on('submit', function() {
  var hiddenValue = $('input[name="product_id"]', this).val();
});
```

But it would be better to just use AJAX.